# OpenVPN Windows Server 2008 R2 Enabling NAT

Tags: vpn, firewall, windows-server-2008, routing, openvpn

I want to redirect all traffic through the VPN.

### - server.ovpn:

```
port 1200
proto udp
dev tun
ca "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenVPN\\config\\server.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenVPN\\config\\server.key"
dh "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenVPN\\config\\dh2048.pem"
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-to-client
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenVPN\\config\\ta.key" 0 
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

client.ovpn:
Code:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote disaderp.eu 1200
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
tls-auth ta.key 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

- I edited IpEnableRuter in registry to `1`.
- I added rules to firewall
- And yes, I can ping my server

When I connect to this VPN:
- Ping/tracert shows: Time limit exceded
- I can't even ping to 10.8.0.1(VPN server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to install NAT on my server.

I posted a wikipost on OpenVPN: [NatOverWINDOWS2008](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/NatOverWindows2008?version=1)